# eBird API with Python

Tags: python

Please help me get started with the ebird.api library for python.

```
from ebird.api import list_regions

states = list_regions('subnational1', 'US')
```

When I run this code it shows a HTTP 410 Gone Error

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample R code for doing this job. Use this as an example and convert this into python.

```
h <- new_handle()
handle_setheaders(h, "X-eBirdApiToken" = "paste your token here")  
req <-curl_fetch_memory(paste0("https://ebird.org/ws2.0/product/checklist/view/", Checklist),h)
```

Comment: How to convert it to Python, I have 0 knowledge about R